# Por que o print_r imprime antes do echo?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte `array`:

```
$array = array(10,20,30);
print_r($array);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
)
```

---

Se eu imprimir com `echo` antes do `print_r`:

```
echo 'primeiro: ';
print_r($array);
```

Saída:

```
primeiro: Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
)
```

---

Se eu imprimir concatenando, o `print_r` é impresso antes:

```
echo 'primeiro: ' . print_r($array);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
)
primeiro: 1
```

Ainda, imprime esse `1` na frente do `primeiro`.

---

Por que isso acontece ? O que é esse `1` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Porque `print_r` retorna antes:

[`print_r`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php) retorna um valor. Por conta disso, [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php) aguarda todas as operações dentro de seus parâmetros antes de executar para poder imprimir o valor que `print_r` retornou.

Isso seria análogo a fazer uma operação matemática dentro do `echo`: primeiro se resolverá a operação dentro, para depois demonstrar o valor.

### Porque retorna `1`:

De acordo com a documentação de `print_r`:

> Quando o parâmetro return for TRUE, esta função retornará uma string.
>   Caso contrário, o valor retornado será TRUE.

Como o parâmetro `return` não foi definido, e ele é FALSE por padrão, a função `print_r` está retornando TRUE. Isso é convertido para `"1"` dentro do `echo`.

Comment: Acho que será interessante dizer que com parametro `return` a `true` vai dar exatamente o resultado que o autor da pergunta pretendia, e talvez exemplificando como chamaria nesse caso.